# Excel VB Macro to find value from another sheet then change a cell value in current sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file that has two worksheets. I need to run a macro that looks down column A on sheet2 until it's blank. It needs to look for the value from the cell in sheet2 column A on sheet1. If found then change the value of the column AP. If not found then skip to the next search for the next value.

This is what I have so far. I have been able to fix it to where I no longer get errors but it doesn't have results either. It shows and seems to run but no changes are made to cell("AP","row value found") on sheet1.

```
Sub dataChange()
    Dim myRow As Integer
    Dim srch As Integer
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    myRow = 1
    srch = 1
    While Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).Value <> ""
        If Sheet1.Range("A" & CStr(srch)).Value = Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).Value Then
            Sheet1.Range("AP" & CStr(srch)).Value = "HOUSTON"
        End If
        srch = srch + 1
        myRow = myRow + 1
    Wend
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the rows match up? Also, it's easier to use `cells` (for me anyways).

Comment: I tried the code and it works. Although you need an `Exit Sub` before the `Err_Execute:` so you do not get an error message even if everything executed just fine. And you should definetely change the variable declarations from `Integer` to `Long`. Integers can only hold numbers up to 32767. Bad idea to use those to traverse over 1048576 rows. So, since everything is working - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's best to provide a sample of input, expected output, and what results you are not getting. I going to guess you need a nested loop - srch is the outer and myRow is the inner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is comparing `A1` from `Sheet1` to `A1` in `Sheet2`. I think you want to compare `A1` in `Sheet1` to all of `ColumnA` in `Sheet2`. Therefore, you need an outer loop.

The below is your code, modified to accomplish this. It also incorporates Leviathan's comment to change `Integer`'s to `Long`, and inserted the Exit Sub in the appropriate location.

When Sheet2 looks like this ...

[image]

I get this result on Sheet1 ...

[image]

The code ...

```
Sub dataChange()
    Dim myRow As Long, srch As Integer
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    myRow = 1
    srch = 1
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(srch, 1).VALUE <> ""
        Do While Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).VALUE <> ""
            If Sheet1.Cells(srch, 1).VALUE = Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).VALUE Then
                Sheet1.Range("AP" & srch).VALUE = "HOUSTON"
                Exit Do
            End If
            myRow = myRow + 1
        Loop
        myRow = 1
        srch = srch + 1
    Loop
    Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```